# Running datadriven unit tests - System.ObjectDisposedException: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot write to a closed TextWriter

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, mstest

I am trying to run our data driven unit tests using VSTS2012(mstest.exe) & TFSBuild by specifying the parallelTestCount  attribute in remote.testsettings file.
    We have some Console.WriteLine statements that write some data as part of the test.

If I have plain unit tests that are NOT data driven then the console logging works fine.
But for datadriven tests with 2 or more rows, test logs the data for the first row. From the 2nd row onwards I see unpredictable results:

- either no data is written
- or the output gets jumblded with other data rows(means: row3 data gets logged for row4 etc.,)

My test with a datasource just prints the data values and a sleep statement. I have 5 tests similar to below one.
The test datafile has 2 rows.

Error Message:

```
Initialization method ParallelTestDataDriven.UnitTest1.TestInit threw exception.     
System.ObjectDisposedException: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot write to a closed TextWriter..
```

I ried to work around using

- TraceSource or
- log4Net.

But in all these cases I see that the 2nd data row onwards is NOt getting logged to the console.

Comment: Can you post some code that reproduces this error?  Are you redirecting the console output to a file using `SetOut`?

Comment: [TestMethod][DataSource]("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|DataDirectory|\\TData.xml", "T1", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)] public void MyTest1() { Console.WriteLine(testContext.DataRow["val1"].ToString(); } Initialization method ParallelTestDataDriven.UnitTest1.TestInit threw exception. System.ObjectDisposedException: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot write to a closed TextWriter.. Trace: System.IO.__Error.WriterClosed() System.IO.StringWriter.Write(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)

Comment: Sorry I can Not better format the code.

Comment: Edit the question and add the content.  In a comment that is unreadable.